# Helvetica font becomes vague (black becomes gray) in exported pdf figure

Tags: plotting, export, color, fonts

I'm trying to set the font of several labels in my data plot as Helvetica Neuve. When I was working in the notebook, it looks well, for example:

```
figlixo = Plot[ Sin[ x ], { x, 0, 2 \[Pi] },  AxesLabel -> {  Style[ "x", FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue", 20, Black ],  Style[ "Sin(x)", FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue", 20, Black ]  }, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue", 16, Black ], ImageSize -> 600 ]
```

and everything looks fine,
[image: sin(x) plot]
however, when I tried to export it to a pdf file

```
Export[ "lixo.pdf", figlixo ]
```

I got something like,
[image: vagued]
the colour of axes labels becomes light and the thickness decreased. I have tried other fonts like Arial, and things work well there.

So I wonder if there is any way to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Try `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I tried but still doesn't work...